Best alternatives for a fast search on a big table on a Postgres database?
We have an Express API that connects to a Postgres database using Sequelize.
One of our endpoints returns a list of sales, which accepts different query parameters like page, column order, filters, and a search term.
This endpoint performs two queries, one to get a single page of results, given the parameters given, and another to get the count of all elements given the same parameters. Both queries have the same from and where clauses.
Most of the query is exact matches (column = value), but when the search term is provided, 10 ilikes conditions are added to the query:

8 of them are comparison between columns and the search term (name ilike %test name%)

The other 2 are more complex:

One uses concat to get the client's full name:
concat(Client.first_name, ' ', Client.last_name) ILIKE '%Test Name%'

And another one that uses regexp_replace to get an acronym, and allow the user to search by a location name as an acronym:
regexp_replace(Location.name, '([a-z ])+', '', 'g') ILIKE '%ABCD%'




We're testing with the client that has the most data (100k rows aprox), and when those ilikes are not in the query, the endpoint usually takes between 1 and 2 seconds, which is acceptable. But if they are in the query, it takes like 6 seconds. The fact that we do 2 queries makes the difference bigger.
The raw query takes around 600 ms without the ilikes, and around 3 seconds with them. If I do explain analyze to the query, it shows that the ilikes are what take most of the time, especially the one with the concatenation (Client's first and last name).
There are some simple stuff we can do, like reduce the amount of columns we search on (we're evaluating if all of them are necessary), stop doing the acronym thing, and do something else instead of that concat for the full name, like the || operator (which I'm trying to do on Sequelize). Also we should use indexes.
But other than that, what would you recommend to do? I'm evaluating using Elasticsearch, but it may be overkill and needs time to set up and maintain.
I also read about Full Search Text on Postgres, which would make searching much faster, and would give us more advanced search features (similar to Elasticsearch), would you recommend it? I think you would pair this with gist or gin indexes, right?
Any other recommendation?

Please include some examples.  All I can get from your prose is that when you do nothing, it takes 1 to 2 second to do nothing, but when you do something, it takes longer.

I said "when the search is performed", if the api doesn't get a search term, all of those 10 ilikes conditions get removed from the query, and the api call takes 1 to 2 seconds, doesn't matter what else I do in the query. But when the query has those 10 ilikes, it always takes around 6 seconds. So clearly those 10 ilikes are the issue, not the rest of the query, or the rest of the api implementation. I thought it was clear, but I'm editing the question to be more explicit, I'm gonna include EXPLAIN ANALYZE results too.

Right, FTS in Postgres may be sufficiently powerful for your use case, and it works well for me. Now this question is either asking for recommendations or opinion-based, both of which are close reasons. If you want to ask how to apply full-text search capabilities to your table in Postgres, remove all recommendation requests and provide an [MRE] instead. Mandatory reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055. Tell us about your purpose, example query with values, table structure, existing indexes, constraints, pg version, impl. restrictions, etc. Make it detailed and focused.

As an aside, applying regex_replace to 100k rows is a no-go, no index can help with that. This usually can be mitigated by normalizing your data such that a column represents individual entity, not something combined (in some cases that could be a generated column, in other cases the "full version" will be generated, etc.). Same with "ILIKE" unless you are doing a prefix search (pattern not starting with %), but full-text search (tsvector, tsquery) can help with that (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html).

For this problem, I would probably start by evaluating which of the operations is taking the most time. It may be the case that the concatenation and ILIKE clauses are taking up time, or it may be the case that your storage is loading the data into RAM slow. It's very difficult to tell from just a description of the query.
To that end, I highly recommend using Postgres' query plan analysis tools. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html)
EXPLAIN ANALYZE will give you a query plan (the internal execution steps that postgres is taking), which you can then copy-paste into a query plan visualizer like dalibo (https://explain.dalibo.com/).
Once you've done that, you can see plainly which exact part of your query is taking the most time.
That said, if you haven't indexed the columns that you are searching on, that is step 0. Everything after indexing is an afterthought. Correct indexing will give you 90%+ time saved on many queries. Everything else is on the order of 5 or 10%.
Note that a regular b-tree postgres index on a string column will only actually be used by the postgres query planner if certain conditions are met. Most importantly, it will only be used when searching for substrings that are at the start of the overall string.
To get around this, you will need to use a postgres full text search index. The choice of GIN or GIST indexes is very very minor when compared to the time save of simply having an index at all.

Thanks, I did EXPLAIN ANALYZE (I edited the question btw), and yeah, the ilike conditions is the part of the query takes most of the time, and, inside those conditions, both the regexp_replace and concat calls take the most time. So, the next steps are making sure we have indexes for everything we need, hopefully removing the acronym search, and then evaluating using postgres FTS, I'll ask my team if searching for substrings at the start of the string is enough . Thanks!
